# OnClick for 2/3 recycler views in a fragment (which itself is hosted/placed on another fragment) not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I have three recycler views in a fragment (which itself is hosted/placed on another fragment), and the onClick for the 2nd and 3rd fragment don't work (1st works perfectly fine),I tried everything...here is my code:

the 2nd Recycler View adapter class:
RecentSongsAdapter.java

```
    package com.myapp.beatify;
    
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
    
    import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
    
    import java.util.List;
    
    public class RecentSongsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecentSongsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
        private List<CreateSong> mRecentSongList;
        private OnItemClickListener mListener;
    
        public interface OnItemClickListener {
            void onItemClick(int position);
        }
    
        public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
            mListener = listener;
        }
    
        public RecentSongsAdapter(List<CreateSong> mRecentSongList) {
            this.mRecentSongList = mRecentSongList;
        }
    
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view;
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.create_recent_songs, parent, false);
            MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view, mListener);
            return myViewHolder;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Glide.with(holder.imageView.getContext()).load(mRecentSongList.get(position).getImgURL()).into(holder.imageView);
            holder.textView.setText(mRecentSongList.get(position).getTxt());
        }
    
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mRecentSongList.size();
        }
    
        public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public ImageView imageView;
            public TextView textView;
    
            public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
                super(itemView);
                this.imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recent_img);
                this.textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recent_txt);
    
                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (listener != null) {
                            int position = getAdapterPosition();
    
                            if (position == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                                listener.onItemClick(position);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    
    }
```

The xml file for it:
create_recent_songs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/create_recent_RV"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="190dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/recent_img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:src="@drawable/app_logo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/recent_txt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/artifika"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Shape Of You"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

The third Recycler View adapter class:
OurPicksAdapter.java

```
package com.myapp.beatify;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.List;

public class OurPicksAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OurPicksAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private List<CreateSong> mOurPicksList;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public OurPicksAdapter(List<CreateSong> mSongList) {
        this.mOurPicksList = mSongList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.create_our_picks, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view, mListener);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
//        holder.imageView.setImageResource(mSongList.get(position).getImgURL());
        Glide.with(holder.imageView.getContext()).load(mOurPicksList.get(position).getImgURL()).into(holder.imageView);
        holder.textView.setText(mOurPicksList.get(position).getTxt());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mOurPicksList.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView textView;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);
            this.imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.our_img);
            this.textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.our_txt);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();

                        if (position == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            listener.onItemClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The xml file for it:
create_our_picks.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/create_our_RV"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="190dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/our_img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:src="@drawable/app_logo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/our_txt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/artifika"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Shape Of You"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Can you add the code where you instantiate the adapters? Did you debug with breakpoint?

Comment: Actually I couldn't add the code since It didn't fit here,ok so will you have a look at the code if I send a github link to it?Also tell me where should I add a break point and debug

Comment: @KevinRobatel do you want me the send the code where I instantiate the adapters ?I mean in a pastebin or some code sharing site?

Comment: https://www.codepile.net/pile/rG8PR0GW  ,
here is the code where I have instantiated my adapters @KevinRobatel,
(ignore the huge urls that Ive used to load images)

Answer (score 0):

I take a look at https://www.codepile.net/pile/rG8PR0GW and maybe, you should move the `oAdapter.setOnItemClickListener` call before the `ourRecyclerView.setAdapter`.

Like this:

```java
    private void createUserRecentRecyclerView() {
        recentRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.user_recent_RV);
        recentRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        rAdapter = new RecentSongsAdapter(recentList);
        rAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(
                new RecentSongsAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(int position) {
                        Log.e("Info", "Connected");
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        recentRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        recentRecyclerView.setAdapter(rAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: will try this out

Comment: update:-
Still not working :(,do you see any other fault in the code?my first recycler view is working by the way and here is the code to that:
https://www.codepile.net/pile/rLWzxWPl
and its xml file:
https://www.codepile.net/pile/XKl7qaz7
xml code to where my fragments are hosted:
https://www.codepile.net/pile/WAp0EKAE